# Provide unbiased estimator for known distribution and prove it is unbiased

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I am trying to solve an old exercise from a statistics exam but I don't know the subject well and I hit a wall. You are given the following distribution:

\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{2g+1}{2g}x^\frac{1}{2g}
\end{align*}

With $g$ positive and $0\le x\le 1$.

I've already found an estimator for $g$, however now I am asked to find an unbiased estimator for its mean $\mu$ and prove that it is unbiased. I don't know how to do that, at least not for this particular distribution. I already found the value of $\mu$ by integrating (I found it to be $(2g+1)/(4g+1)$), and I know I somehow have to prove that the average of the estimator is equal to μ but idk how to do that. Can anyone help?

Comment: Alright, yeah, sorry, I had a bit of a brain fart, that's what I meant.

Comment: I fixed it now, and yes, it is a probability density function with a parameter g.

Comment: So what is the mean of this distribution? Do you have to find its unbiased estimator based on a single observation $X$? Please state the problem precisely.

Comment: The mean of the distribution is what I derived through integration and mentioned in my post. It wasn't given. You have to find an estimator based on n observations of X.

Comment: The problem doesn't state anything more, I can't state it more precisely because this is how it is stated.

Comment: I mean that cannot be the expectation since you did not have the right pdf to start with. Please add all relevant info in the body of the post, not in comments.

Comment: I edited the post before my final comments and I made it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now I am asked to find an unbiased estimator for its mean $\mu$ and
> prove that it is unbiased.

The simply way to answer is this.

An unbiased estimator for the $\mu$, the mean of the population is the sample mean

$$\hat{\mu}=\bar{X}_n$$

To prove it is unbiased is very easy

$$\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \mathbb{E}[X_1]=\frac{1}{n}\cdot n \mu=\mu$$

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit confused, I should begin to find a MLE estimator for θ; Also we haven't been taught the beta distribution in that class so I don't think I can use that. There has to be a different way...

Comment: @AndreasC : Understood and edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I could just do that! Nice.